# Django model, using auth_group as a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django-models, foreign-keys

I would like to use the `auth_group` table as a foreign key in my custom model :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(auth_group)
```

I cant find a mention on how to reference this table.

I've seen `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, but couldnt see anything for `auth_group`

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The table `auth_group` is referenced by the `Group` model of the `auth` app, with default naming.

So to make a ForeignKey to an object in that table your model would be:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

This gives me the following problem:

```
No Such Column: cmit_question.qs_f_responsible_id
```

Details in here: [In Django, How to call the 'User Group' as a foreign key in a model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500232/in-django-how-to-call-the-user-group-as-a-foreign-key-in-a-model-class)