# In Django, How to call the 'User Group' as a foreign key in a model class?

Tags: django, django-models

I created a model class named Question. I want only particular user group can answer the questions. NOW, How can I bring a foreign key here from user group?

In my DB there is a Question Table. There will be a lot of questions. But not all the users are allowed to view or answer the questions. This will depend on in which user group the user belongs to. So I have to specify which user group is allowed to answer the question in the Question table. Now, I have to create a field in question table where I (or more specifically the admin) can select an user group. To do so, I have to link the "Group" table as a foreign key in the table.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Question(models.Model):

    # Fields
    qs_title = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    qs_status = models.IntegerField()

    # Relationship Fields
    qs_f_track = models.ForeignKey('cmit.QuestionTrack', )
    responsible = models.ForeignKey(Group) # (Is this line Okay? not working though.)
```

The above code is not working as when the admin is trying to add a question it says,

```
No Such Column: cmit_question.qs_f_responsible_id
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a `Question` instance? Or trying to implement a `permission` system? Your question is incomplete

Comment: Both, In fact (though I am not sure sure whether my procedure is right or not!). Let me explain.
In my DB there is a Question Table. There will be a lot of questions. But not all the users are allowed to view or answer the questions. This will depend on in which user group the user belongs to. So I have to specify which user group is allowed to answer the question in the Question table. 
Now, I have to create a field in question table where I (or more specifically the admin) can select an user group. To do so, I have to link the "Group" table as a foreign key in the table.

Comment: [Godfrey Goodluck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13368569/godfrey-goodluck) wrote in an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64813550/12695027) "Have you created a group in your admin?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Got a solution... Kind of, per se...
The relation should be Many To Many... 
Lets see the code...

```
qs_f_group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
qs_group = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True)

def get_group(self):
    return self.qs_f_group.all().first()
```

The function is to get the first entry of the group.
Thanks a lot.

(Though I am not using the same. A function wont help me at all. 
Rather I went static:

```
CHOICE_LIST = (('0', 'Undefined'), ('staffGroup', 'staffGroup'), ('staffGroup02', 'staffGroup02'), ('staffGroup03', 'staffGroup03'), ('staffGroup04', 'staffGroup04'), ('staffGroup05', 'staffGroup05'),)
qs_responsible = models.CharField(max_length=350, default=0, choices=CHOICE_LIST, verbose_name='Responsible Party')
```

Not recommended, Obviously! )

Comment: One more thing.... Can you please advice that how can I get a list of the users in the view (will change automatically with user changes) so that I can use that as a choice list automatically?